# How is the start of a bounty grace period a community milestone?

Tags: support, bug, bounties, email-notification, expired-bounty

I received an email announcing the start of my bounty grace period:

[image]

At the bottom it says:

> You’re receiving this message because you reached a Meta Stack Exchange community milestone.

How is this a community milestone? Or is it a bug?

Comment: That is a canned line that appears on emails sent from the same script. It's there for compliance with CAN-SPAM.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog Naturally, but it should be a category by itself with a different line. Compliance can still be reached with different wording. However, it would not be an easy fix I suspect.